# PyCapture2 Video through opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, flycapture

Having trouble importing my Point Grey Chameleon3 camera through opencv and PyCapture2. Currently Taking photos/images individually but want a constant flow.I think it has to do with camera.retrieveBuffer() but can not find a way around.

```
import PyCapture2
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

bus = PyCapture2.BusManager()
numCams = bus.getNumOfCameras()
camera = PyCapture2.Camera()
uid = bus.getCameraFromIndex(0)
camera.connect(uid)
camera.startCapture()

while True:
    image = camera.retrieveBuffer()
    row_bytes = float(len(image.getData())) / float(image.getRows());
    cv_image = np.array(image.getData(), dtype="uint8").reshape((image.getRows(), image.getCols()) );
    cv2.imshow('frame',cv_image)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

If anyone has any pointers or links to more documentation would be greatly appreciated Thanks

Comment: not sure I understand your problem... your current program works, but it shows images one at the time and not in a flow? have you tried to put a number like 10 or 30 in the cv2.waitKey() function? that should make your loop update the frame in a flow. Or you mean that it can only retrieve one image and then the program hangs/crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a very similar code with a BlackFly camera. The flow problem is because the loop is very slow. You are calling `image.getData()` twice which makes the problem somewhat worse but the main issue is that reading and converting the data into an image format is very slow.

Diving a little deeper and timing some functions on my computer (my image is 1920 by 1200):

`image = camera.retrieveBuffer()` - takes about as much time as the set frame rate.

`image.getData()` takes about 220 ms.

`np.array(image.getData(), dtype="uint8").reshape((image.getRows(), image.getCols()) )` takes about 540 ms.

So the refresh rate cannot be faster than that.

Comment: Thanks Mate,Do you have anymore information on the Pycapture documentation. I'm Currently having trouble configuring all the camera setting. I am following https://qiita.com/YutaYANAGITYAYA/items/1ab61671d8cc69d7ade7 but my Japanese is in poor form right now

Comment: After installation, the pycapture folder includes a bunch of examples and a document describing all of the different classes.

Comment: I spoke to Point Grey about this issue and it seems like they fixed it. They sent me a beta release that works well (the full release is still not available).

Comment: The image.getData() now returns a numpy array and it is way faster. I was able to stream a video with a fairly high refresh rate.

Comment: Which version we're talking about of the SDK lib?

Answer (score 1):

I found the PyCapture2 library [here](https://www.ptgrey.com/support/downloads).
I downloaded the library, then I navigated to my python install then into the docs.

> PYTHON_PATH/PyCapture2/docs

The path can also be found by:

```
import PyCapture2
PyCapture2.__path__
```

Anyways, If you are looking for the docs or the module itself, you can find them there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "cvs.waitkey()" time and it should work:

> e.g. `cv2.waitKey(10)`